# How to get city & country name from googlemap in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation, flutter-layout

does anyone have an idea on how to open a google map screen where the user can search for his address and at validation the screen get closed and the city + country of selected address get filled on a Textfield, please?

Answer (score 0):

For implementing "Google Places Autocomplete" for a simple Textfield, you can start from this [package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_google_places_autocomplete).

Comment: Can you pull out some relevant info from there and include it in your answer (such as the name of the package and how to use it)? Then if the link ever changes the information is still accessible on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the flutter_google_places api. It's super simple and easy to use. As you type in locations it will auto suggest the city, state, country. This data is then available in the `prediction.description`

Here is an example:

```
placesAutoCompleteTextField(TextEditingController controller) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: GooglePlaceAutoCompleteTextField(
        textEditingController: controller,
        googleAPIKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
        inputDecoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Search your location"),
        debounceTime: 800,
        countries: const ["in", "fr", "usa"],
        isLatLngRequired: true,
        getPlaceDetailWithLatLng: (Prediction prediction) {
          print("placeDetails " + prediction.lng.toString());
        },
        itmClick: (Prediction prediction) {
          if (prediction.description != null) {
            controller.text = prediction.description!;

            controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                TextPosition(offset: prediction.description!.length));

            print('City, State, Country: ${prediction.description}');
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

This returns a TextField type widget that can search places. As you type it autofills locations and when you select one the `prediction` variable gets updated with location data.

Hope this helps!